# JS/PHP automatically enter desktop version on mobile

Tags: javascript

So I've been working on a website for quite some time now and I have many elements that simply don't work with phones but I've noticed if I use the option desktop version everything is scaled and centered correctly. Now I want all my users to automatically check this option via javascript or something until I get the mobile version of the website working.

I'm not a pro, so please keep the answers simple. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you remove the CSS for the mobile version until the mobile version is working? That would leave all clients (even mobile) with the desktop CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries for that. There is a nice [MDN Web Docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Requ%C3%AAtes_m%C3%A9dia/Utiliser_les_Media_queries) that you can check. To check if you're on a phone you can use the `max-width` CSS property.

**Example:**
*If the browser window is 500px or smaller, the background color will be `lightblue`*

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I wanted. If you open the settings on a phone's browser, you can open the website in desktop mode which scales everything up.

Answer (score 0):

I explained it poorly. What I was trying to do is enable the checkbox in the mobile browser's menu that requests the desktop version of the website.

Instead, I have now improved my CSS skills and can make websites behave correctly on lower DPI devices.